# ASTM B209 does not list Aluminium Alloy 1070

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials

This is my first post.

We manufacture products using various grades or alloys of Aluminium sheet, one of our common alloys is 1070. In referencing the ASTM B209/209M-21a standard I do not see 1070 listed, it does list 1060 and 1100.

Which ASTM or other governing standard would list alloy sheet 1070 composition and mechanical properties?